# Oracle SQL - Count on one column and display information from other column's/records

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am a complete novice to SQL so this may be a stupid question. I would like to look for duplicates values in TR_VALUE.NEW VALUE and display additional column information from other columns in other records. E.g. TR_VALUE.OLD_VALUE.

The query below runs fine if I remove TR_VALUE.OLD_VALUE but I would like to display other data about the duplicates.

```
SELECT  
    "TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE", "TR_VALUE"."OLD_VALUE", 
    COUNT("TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE") 
FROM
    (("DB1"."WORKORDER" "WORKORDER" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "DB1"."TR_VALUE" "TR_VALUE" ON "WORKORDER"."FG_LOTNO" = "TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "DB1"."STANDARD" "STANDARD" ON "WORKORDER"."STANDARD_ID" = "STANDARD"."ID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "DB1"."TR_BATCH" "TR_BATCH" ON "TR_VALUE"."TR_BATCH_ID" = "TR_BATCH"."ID"
GROUP BY 
    "TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE"
HAVING 
    COUNT("TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE") > 1
```

Comment: Then please show some sample data and what your result is supposed to look like. If the new_value 123 is found four times, then there are up to four different old values. How do you want to display them?

Comment: And please get your query readable. All upper case makes it hard to read. No indentions make it hard to read. You can remove all those nasty double quotes, too. You can use short mnemonic table alias names, e.g. w for workorder, v for tr_value, s for standard. And is it just me? I find joins with parentheses hard to read. And they are completely superfluous in your query. I'd remove them. At last highlight the SQL statement use the `{}` button to format this as code.

Comment: DBMS - Oracle 11g. Sorry about the format of the query, I exported the query from Crystal Reports and it places everything in upper case. I will address.

Comment: I wanted to display the new values that contain the duplicates and the old values side by side. So for the 4 duplicates there would be 4 different old values.

Comment: Okay, please show us. Make up a few sample rows and then show the rows and columns you want to have in the result. As mentioned there can be many old values per new value, so how is this supposed to be displayed in the results exactly? A query result is a table. How many columns shall that result table have? What shall they contain?

Comment: By the way, why are all these outer joins? Do you want to count workorders that have no tr_values? If so, `count(new_value)` will be wrong and result in 0. And you outer join the standard table, because workorder.standard_id is nullable?

Comment: Thorsten, sorry a complete beginner to SQL trying to interpret an ERP system database. I will have a look at the joins I build the basics to prove the theory and the logic in crystal reports and then export the SQL query. Probably out of my depth. Don't want to count works orders that have a null value all of them will have a number.

Comment: So after all you look at the new_value table in order to find new_values that exist multifold in that table? Or that link to multiple workorders?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your query to be working, Just add 1 more column to group by clause -

```
SELECT  
    "TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE",
    "TR_VALUE"."OLD_VALUE", 
    COUNT("TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE") 
FROM
    (("DB1"."WORKORDER" "WORKORDER" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "DB1"."TR_VALUE" "TR_VALUE" ON "WORKORDER"."FG_LOTNO" = "TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "DB1"."STANDARD" "STANDARD" ON "WORKORDER"."STANDARD_ID" = "STANDARD"."ID") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    "DB1"."TR_BATCH" "TR_BATCH" ON "TR_VALUE"."TR_BATCH_ID" = "TR_BATCH"."ID"
GROUP BY 
    "TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE",
    "TR_VALUE"."OLD_VALUE"
HAVING 
    COUNT("TR_VALUE"."NEW_VALUE") > 1
```